# Android Font Face in simple ListViewAdapter

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to change the font of the items in my ListView using a .ttf file. The problem is that I am unable to access the getAssets() method. What should I do to modify my code?

```
public class ListViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public ListViewArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_address, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Thin.ttf");
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_address, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.selectAddressPt);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        if(position%2==1){
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darker_blue);
        }else{
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_blue);
        }

        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SelectAddress.enableButton();
            }

        });

    return rowView;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare font in your activity:

```
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Thin.ttf");
 //and pass font as argument in constructor.     
 ListViewArrayAdapter(context,values,font);
```

now update your `ListViewArrayAdapter` class code as this:

```
public class ListViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
public Typeface font;

public ListViewArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values,TypeFace ttf) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_address, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;  
    this.font=ttf;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_address, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.selectAddressPt);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        textView.setTypeFace(font);

        if(position%2==1){
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darker_blue);
        }else{
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_blue);
        }

        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SelectAddress.enableButton();
            }

        });

    return rowView;

}
```

Comment: There was a small typo on the TypeFace type (needs to be Typeface). Besides that, this code worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
this.context.getAssets();
```

Comment: this.context.getAssets() gave me an error, but this.getContext().getAssets() worked